# grid problem two restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways we can "go" from (0,0) to (7,5) if we mustn't go through segments [(2,2),(3,2)] and [(4,2),(4,3)]. Solution (m+n over n)(without restrictions) is 792 checked using pascal triangle. Using also pascal triangle method with restrictions I get 492. Using including/excluding method is the easiest way to solve this problem =>intersection of (A1 and A2) = |U| - |A1C U A2C|

*C= complement 
but I cant get that solution this way 792 - 492 = **300** forbidden ways.
How can I reach those -300 comb. using union of this restricted pathways? I know that there are 60 combinations to the segment [(2,2),(2,3)]. (4!/2!*2!)*(5!/3!*2!)
[pascal's triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7g4gP.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

[Note that for the restricted pathway through $(4,2)-(4,3)$ you need the number of routes to $(4,2)$ and then the number of routes from $(4,3)$ to$(7,5)$.]

**Inclusion-exclusion method**

The number of routes through $(2,2)-(3,2)$ is $\begin{pmatrix}4 \\2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}7 \\4\end{pmatrix}=210.$

The number of routes through $(4,2)-(4,3)$ is $\begin{pmatrix}6 \\2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}5 \\2\end{pmatrix}=150.$

The number of routes through both is $\begin{pmatrix}4 \\2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}5 \\2\end{pmatrix}=60.$

The answer is therefore $792-210-150+60=492$.